# Feature Selection for Regression Models in R

Tags: r, regression, feature-selection

I’m trying to find a feature selection package in `R` that can be used for regression. Most of the packages implement their methods for classification using a factor or class for the response variable. In particular I’m interested if there’s something using random forest for that purpose. Also if someone knows some good paper in this field would be welcome.

Comment: Check out `caret` package, it has a lot of different tools in it. Also `bestglm` and `leaps` for best subset selection.

Comment: `glmnet` implements LASSO and friends, which does feature selection for regression problems.